# Generate files in 'src' for maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, soap, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am new to Spring Boot and not familiar with how SOAP web service work.

In the pom file I have following configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>calculator.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The 'generatePackage' creates source files in target/generatedsources/calculator/wsdl.

I want them to be generated in '{$basedir}/src/java' so that I can use the services in my code. I tried putting the above entry in the 'generatePackage' tag. But still the files are getting generated in 'target'.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is an awful idea. The generated code will not be automatically cleaned for you and you may accidentally commit it to source control. If your IDE does not understand when a plugin generates code for you then you should manually add the `target/generatedsources/` directory to it's source path configuration.

Comment: @SteveC `maven-jaxb2-plugin` automatically adds the generation directory to source paths. IDEs normally pick it up if generation went without problems.

Comment: @lexicore I know that. The OP seemed to have some problem that prevented this from happening, hence my remark.

Comment: @SteveC I was able to add those in target/generatedsources/. The reason I wanted those in src/java is I wanted to use the methods in my client code. If I don't put those in 'src/java' it throws compilation error. For examle, there is a generated AddResponse.java file that I want to use in my client. If I don't have it in my 'src/java', it doesn't compile and I am not able to use the services. Is there anyway I can remove these complilation errors. Thanks for your inputs though!

Comment: Is it your IDE that can't compile it or Maven? If it's the IDE, which one? Which version?

Answer (score 5):

You can configure target directory via `generateDirectory`. See:

https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Controlling-the-Output

But as Steve C pointed out, you should not put generated code under `src/main/java`. Keep generated code separate from manually written code. Do not check generated code into VCS.

Answer (score 5):

As other users said, you should create a different module which will have the generated sources, let's call it generated for convenience.

Then your "main" code/module (the code that will use the generated sources) *will reference generated in its dependencies*.

When maven will run its lifecycle, it *will figure out for you* which modules to build first based on the defined dependencies and you will not have compilation problems.

Will give you a small example to make it more clear. We will build a multimodule project. Will use xsd instead of wsdl to generate Java classes, cos I have one available, but the principle is the same, just using maven plugin in the submodule to generate sources. The parent pom would look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.multimodule</groupId>
  <artifactId>multimodule-demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>multimodule.demo</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>application</module>
    <module>generated</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

The parent pom references two submodules: application and generated. The generated module has the following xsd for class generation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="shiporder">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="shipto">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

And its pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>multimodule.demo</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example.multimodule</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.multimodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>generated</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>-Xequals -XhashCode -Xfluent-api</arguments>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                    <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-fluent-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Now the application module, will reference the generated module as a dependency:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>multimodule.demo</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example.multimodule</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.multimodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.multimodule</groupId>
            <artifactId>generated</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And we will create a simple main to use the generated sources and demo it working:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Shiporder shiporder = new Shiporder();
        shiporder.setOrderid("Some orderId");
        System.out.println( shiporder.getOrderid() );
    }
```

Run from the directory of the parent (multimodule-demo): mvn clean install

You will see that your project builds successfully, because maven is smart enough to build them in the proper order.

Comment: hello, your answer was very helpful. i followed your instructions but in my `main` method intellij could not resolve the symbol. is there some sort of "`import`" that needs to be done? thank u

Comment: hi @ShiZhang, happy that you find it helpful. Which symbol it cannot resolve? ShipOrder? Is the class generated under the generated module? Did you add the dependency in your main module (where the main is)?